# Should I include arguments in views_embed_view or in a hook_views_pre_view function?

Tags: 7, views

I have a tonne of views across my site and pretty much all of them need to have their arguments passed programmatically.

I'm wondering which method is best assuming I'm using views_embed_view to print all of them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`views_embed_view` takes arguments as the third parameter. Since you have to use that to print a view on-demand, might as well pass them along there.